# PHP Explode comma separated values with date

Tags: php, explode

I'm using explode to parse a string of comma separated values into variables.  No problem there.  The issue I'm having is that one of the values is a date in the format:  May 3, 2013.  So the explode is picking up on the comma in the date.  Do I have any options for getting around this?  I don't have much control over the source (the original string) so I'm trying to come up with a way to work with what I've got.

```
$CONTENT = 'blue,red,purple,May 2, 2013,orange,green';
list($valueA, $valueB, $valueC, $valueD, $valueE, $valueF) = explode(',', $CONTENT);
```

Thank you!

Comment: is the `$CONTENT` variable correct? I think you meant `$CONTENT="blue,red,purple..."`, right?

Comment: use str_getcsv() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: @MatthiasLaug Yes, sorry about that.  Corrected!

Comment: is the original content always formed like that?

Comment: I believe you can't do anything if it's formed like that, unless you can search for a workaround to change the separator to something other than ',' in the script that generates $CONTENT

Comment: Fix whatever's generating the string in the first place. That'll pay off better than trying to fix the broken output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to split your string. This is based on the assumption, that there is not whitespace between two words if it is used as a seperator.

```
$CONTENT = 'blue,red,purple,May 2, 2013,orange,green';
$result = preg_split('/,(?! )/', $CONTENT);
```

your string will result correctly in

```
array(6) {
   [0]=>
      string(4) "blue"
   [1]=>
      string(3) "red"
   [2]=>
      string(6) "purple"
   [3]=>
      string(11) "May 2, 2013"
   [4]=>
      string(6) "orange"
   [5]=>
     string(5) "green"
}
```

so once you are using your list expression again, your variables should be set correctly

```
list($valueA, $valueB, $valueC, $valueD, $valueE, $valueF) = preg_split('/,(?! )/', $CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the comma by finding the value in the array and replacing the comma with a special symbol, then after the explode replace the special symbol with a comma.

Comment: How do you differentiate between a comma inside a date and a comma separating two list items, though?

Comment: Oh I didn't read your question properly. Maybe use regex to try and find any valid dates (month day year) then take them out, explode, put them back in?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to use a regular expression to look for something matching the pattern of a date, replace the comma with something else, then after you explode the string, replace that special character with a comma again.

It's messy, but if you genuinely have no control over the string coming in, there's probably not a lot you can do.

Comment: Here's the regex to match the date: \w{3,10}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}

Comment: Assuming it stays in that format, though - which it might, but who knows, really. But yeah, that'll work for the given example, thanks for including that.

Comment: No problem.  Unfortunately, we all have to make a lot of assumptions when answering on a limited subset of data :-)

Comment: Thanks all.  Really appreciate the help.  I'm going to go back and see if the content string can be formatted differently so there's some level of predictability.  Seems like that's the only sure fire way.

Comment: If you can get it, see if you can just get them to send it as csv, with values in quotes. something like

`"value one","red","May 1, 2013"`

There's all kinds of stuff out there for parsing CSV, and even if you do it yourself, should be a little easier.